# packet retransmission

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming

I have a scenario where multiple clients connect to a TCP server. When any of the clients sends a packet to the server, the server is supposed to have a retransmission timer and keep sending that packet to another server until it receives a reply. How do I go about setting up this retransmission mechanism? I'm doing this on Linux in C.

Comment: does this mean you have multiple clients, say C1, C2 and C3 and a server S1 which sends packets to S2? If yes then, are you asking for retransmission between S1 - S2 or C1 to S1? If you are asking for client to S1 then that is taken care of by TCP or even for S1-S2 traffic, if you are using TCP connection, it is taken care of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing this is an assignment. I had something similar where our channel was purposefully being corrupted.

I would suggest you follow something similar.

1. Send packet.
2. start a timer.
3. if an ACK (acknowledgment) is not received within a certain amount of time, then go back to step 1.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a TCP socket, retransmit will happen automatically.  Admittedly, if you want more control, you'll need to use UDP and handle the retransmit yourself.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, the location of the files that contain these TCP config parameters are distro-dependent.  They are in different folders on Red Hat and Ubuntu.